# .NET Core and IIS

Tags: performance, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

We currently have a web api targeting .NET 4 framework which is hosted within IIS using an application pool which is using .NET 4 CLR.

We are investigating migrating the web api from .NET 4 to .NET Core 2.1 (for performance improvements). The web api has other DLL references which have been built using .NET 4 framework. I have a simple proof of concept up and running using .NET Core 2.1 and the references which had been built using .NET 4 framework appear to have imported fine as I can reference them and the project builds.

If I have the new .NET Core 2.1 web api referencing the 3rd party DLLs using .NET framework 4 which is then going to be hosted in IIS using the CLR 4... how would we see any performance increase? If everything is being run using the CLR 4, is that not the bottleneck for performance? Or is it the binaries that the CLR reads being more performant where you will see better performance?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as I'm very confused at the moment!

Thanks

Comment: Getting rid of that dependency would be your best option right now. If you have to stick to .NET Framework, then running ASP.NET Core on it only gives you partial performance gain. https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1 You must also remember that ASP.NET Core is not running on IIS, but Kestrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're handling things. .NET Core 2.0+ fully supports .NET Standard 2.0, which has an API footprint large enough to cover most .NET Framework functionality. As a result, the compiler will let you add a .NET Framework library reference to a project that's actually targeting .NET Core 2.0+. There's no guarantee that the library will *actually* work (and you get a warning to that effect), but unless it's using Windows-specific APIs, there's a very good chance it will function fine.

Assuming this is the case with your .NET Framework libraries and you're actually targeting something like .NET Core 2.1, then you are *not* in fact using .NET Framework, and you don't even need .NET Framework installed on the server you're deploying to. All the requisite framework dependencies will come from the .NET Core runtime, or can even be packaged along with your app if you opt for a self-contained deployment. In that case, once compiled, it's virtually inconsequential that the libraries you referenced actually targeted .NET Framework.

If however the libraries do not work without full .NET Framework, you can still build a .NET Core app, but you'll be forced to continue to target .NET Framework, rather than .NET Core. In that case, you will of course be reliant on the .NET Framework CLR, with the performance drain that entails. That said, an ASP.NET Core app, for example, is still generally more performant than something like an ASP.NET MVC app, so you will get some gains - just not as much as if you were actually targeting .NET Core.

Regardless of what you ultimately end up targeting, your app is actually served via Kestrel. IIS acts merely as a reverse proxy.